# Crawling In python, I can't use the findALL

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

i'm using python 3.x to practice crawling

```
<p style="MARGIN-BOTTOM: 3pt; TEXT-AUTOSPACE: ; mso-pagination: none; mso
padding-alt: 0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt" class="0">
<a href="http://www.blablabla.pdf"    target="_blank">
<strong><img align="center"src="http://blablablablablabla.png"
width="108"></strong></a></p>
```

and p>a

```
<a href="http://BLABLABLABLABLA.pdf"
target="_blank"><strong><img align="center"
src="http://blablablablabla.png"
width="108"></strong></a>
```

and then I used the

```
divTag = soup.find('p', style='MARGIN-BOTTOM:')
```

To get the

```
a href="http://blabla~~~
```

But, i can't get that.

The result(divTag = soup.find('p', style='MARGIN-BOTTOM:') is None.

I don't know why.

Comment: Oh, I got it. I'm idiot...
I have to use the 
   ---- style="MARGIN-BOTTOM: 3pt; TEXT-AUTOSPACE: ; mso-pagination: none; mso-padding-alt: 0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt" -----
I'm so sorry. I learn that I have to use the full text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p style="MARGIN-BOTTOM: 3pt; TEXT-AUTOSPACE: ; mso-pagination: none; mso
padding-alt: 0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt" class="0">
```

the style is

```
"MARGIN-BOTTOM: 3pt; TEXT-AUTOSPACE: ; mso-pagination: none; mso
padding-alt: 0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt"
```

not `MARGIN-BOTTOM`

```
import bs4

html = '''<p style="MARGIN-BOTTOM: 3pt; TEXT-AUTOSPACE: ; mso-pagination: none; mso
padding-alt: 0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt" class="0">
<a href="http://www.auri.re.kr/pdf/UrbanPlanning_BusanJingu.pdf"    target="_blank">
<strong><img align="center"src="http://auri.re.kr/upload/contentsImg/IMG20140922162029.png"
width="108"></strong></a></p>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

Method 1:

```
soup.select_one('p a').get('href')
```

Method 2:

```
soup.select_one('a[href$=".pdf"]').get('href')
```

out:

```
'http://www.auri.re.kr/pdf/UrbanPlanning_BusanJingu.pdf'
```

Comment: Can I find the 'href' using findAll at one go ???

Also, Can I use  regex in findAll ??

Comment: @StackQ  you should reference the document: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree

Comment: @StackQ please accept my answer to close this question, this will save other people a lot time.

Comment: Oh, yes, absolutely. 
I read the document you recommended. Thx :)